# Representability in formal arithmetic

Tags: logic, arithmetic

I'm taking a course in mathematical logic. We've reached the topic "Arithmetization of logic". The course does not prove that the functions below are representable in formal arithmetic. I'm interested in a more detailed solution. Unfortunately, I did not find anything on the Internet. I tried to formalize my question to make it easier for you to understand. Can anyone help me with this problem?

Prove that the following functions are representable in formal arithmetic:

1. primitive "*Zero*" $Z$;
   $$Z: \mathbb{N}_0\to\mathbb{N}_0,\ \ \ \ \ Z(x_1) = 0$$
2. primitive "*Increment*" $N$;
   $$N: \mathbb{N}_0\to\mathbb{N}_0,\ \ \ \ \ N(x_1) = x_1+1$$
3. decrement (limited subtraction 1).

**Definition of representability.**

We will say that the function $f: \mathbb{N}^n_0\to\mathbb{N}_0$ is representable in formal arithmetic, if there is a formula $\varphi$ such that:

1. if $f(a_1,\dots,a_n) = u$ then $\vdash \varphi(\overline{a_1},\dots,\overline{a_n},\overline{u})$
2. if $f(a_1,\dots,a_n) \ne u$ then $\vdash \neg\varphi(\overline{a_1},\dots,\overline{a_n},\overline{u})$
3. for all $a_i \in \mathbb{N}_0$ done $\vdash (\exists x.\varphi(\overline{a_1},\dots,\overline{a_n},x)) \&
       (\forall p.\forall q.\varphi(\overline{a_1},\dots,\overline{a_n},p) \&  \varphi(\overline{a_1},\dots,\overline{a_n},q )\rightarrow p=q)$

Comment: Why is the variable called $x_1$? More importantly, what is the definition of such representability?

Answer (score 1):

I presume that your course defines an $n$-place function $f(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ to be representable if there is a formula $\phi(x_1, \ldots, x_n, y)$ that holds iff $y = f(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$. Then (writing $P$ for the predecessor function) we have
\begin{align*}
y = Z(x) &\Leftrightarrow y = 0 \\
y = N(x) &\Leftrightarrow x < y \land (\forall z(x < z \Rightarrow y \le z)) \\
y = P(x) &\Leftrightarrow x = N(y)
\end{align*}
which shows that your three functions are representable.

Comment: The main problem is that this is just formulas representing primitives in formal arithmetic, and they has not been proven in any way.

Comment: You need to give your definition of representability. I am talking about representability in the complete theory of $\Bbb{N}$, which means that there is nothing to prove (my equivalences are clearly valid in $\Bbb{N}$). If you are talking about representability with respect to a smaller theory such as $PA$, then there is some (metatheoretical) proof to do, but it isn't difficult for any sufficiently strong theory.